# Looking up types from Freebase

Tags: web, freebase

I am trying to find a list of relevant types to a certain string from Freebase, lets say for example i enter Jordan, then i will have a list with types country, person, athlete .. etc.

I have found several ways for the query, for example:

[First Query](http://api.freebase.com/api/service/search?query=jordan)

trying to get the JSON fails, using:

```
$.getJSON('http://api.freebase.com/api/service/search?query=jordan',function (data) {
            console.log(data);
           });
```

There is another [query](http://api.freebase.com/api/service/mqlread?query=%7B%22extended%22%3atrue,%22query%22%3a%5B%7B%22name~=%22%3a%22jordan%22,%22id%22%3anull,%22name%22%3anull,%22type%22%3anull%7D%5D%7D) that gives me better result, as i only get the types here but i also cannot get the JSON file from it.

Will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has probably less to do with freebase and more to do the fact that you can't do cross domain http requests. You are requesting data from api.freebase.com but you are probably hosting this page in another domain.

You can use the JSONP mechanism to circumvent that restriction, here is some documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Read the section JSONP.

Another couple of points:

1. Are you trying to search for all entities that somehow match the word "jordan" or are you looking for exactly all the entities that are named "jordan" ? Your best bet is to use the /search API instead of /mqlread which is for structured database queries.
2. You are also using the legacy API that is deprecated. Here is some docs on the new API:

http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/API

Here's how your request will look (note that you 'll need an API key for production):
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?query=jordan&mql_output=[{%22name%22%20:%20null,%22type%22:[]}]